# ng2 charts - refresh pie chart

Tags: javascript, angular, ng2-charts

Am using ng2-charts - https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts

I have a pie chart, if I hard code the data when I declare the variable at the top of my component.ts file like in the example my pie chart displays.

But I obviously want to make the pie char data dynamic. I can call the data through a service (which is a number), add the number to the data array, and the pie chart does not work. But if I do console log, the array prints out with the new data/number I have added to it.

I need to redraw the table somehow. Can't figure out how.

```
 public pieChartLabels:string[] = ['Red Flags','Green Flags'];
 public pieChartData: number[] = [200, 400];
 public chartType:string = 'pie';
 public redFlagsTotal: any;
 public greenFlagsTotal: any;

constructor(private dataService:flagService) {
    let component = this;
    this.redFlagsTotal =    this.dataService.getRedFlags().then(function(result){
        component.redFlagsTotal = result.length;
        console.log(component.redFlagsTotal);
        component.pieChartData.push(component.redFlagsTotal);
        console.log(component.pieChartData);
    });

    this.greenFlagsTotal =     this.dataService.getGreenFlags().then(function(result){
        component.greenFlagsTotal = result.length;
        console.log(component.greenFlagsTotal);
        component.pieChartData.push(component.greenFlagsTotal);
        console.log(component.pieChartData);
    });
}
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) there's an `.update(duration, lazy)` function, have you read it?

Answer (score 3):

You can hide and show the chart for a millisecond like this:

```
refreshChart(){
    this.mychart.show = false;
    setTimeout(()=>{
        this.mychart.show = true;
    },1);
}
```

in the template use than `mychart.show` with `*ngIf` like this:

```
<div style="display: block">
  <canvas baseChart
          *ngIf="mychart.show"
          [data]="pieChartData"
          [labels]="pieChartLabels"
          [chartType]="pieChartType"
          (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
          (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
</div>
```

in your function than you can use the `refreshChart()` function when you want to refresh the chart.

**EDIT:**

If you reinitialize the array than the char should update automatically, instead of this:

```
component.pieChartData.push(component.greenFlagsTotal);
```

do this:

```
let temp = [...component.pieChartData, ...component.greenFlagsTotal];
component.pieChartData = [...temp];
```

Comment: I had something nasty that only on a reposive site modus. The page-size needed a resize before he could show the data. This wasn't working with other answers therefore a 1 milisec show enable disable worked! The thing is redrawing was needed when the data just was placed in the array like your edit shows only this time there was not such a update done  :( This is a little dirty not show show, but for my page idk,  Big thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped!

Comment: First answer is may not good practice , but best alternative fix "mychart.show".

Answer (score 2):

Solved! Hide the canvas until the data has loaded.

```
    <div *ngIf="pieChartData.length > 1" style="display: block">
    <canvas baseChart
            [data]="pieChartData"
            [labels]="flagPieChartLabels"
            [chartType]="chartType"
            (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
            (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to make your chart data dynamic is to bind the chart directive via ViewChild like so:

```
...
export class HomeComponent {
    @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective)
    public chart: BaseChartDirective;


void updateChart() {
    this.chart.chart.update(); // This re-renders the canvas element.
}
```

Now you can call `updateChart` everytime your dataset has changed to keep your chart up to date!

Comment: this gives error in console:  Cannot read property 'chart' of undefined

Comment: After solving the problem with 'chart'==undefined, it still did not work for me. I guess this would be the proper solution if the library was less buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the canvas with *ngIf reload the whole component.

It seems that if you push data and label then remove them after 1 ms, it will reload the correct chart data.

```
  reloadChart(){
    this.pieChartLabels.push('reload');
    this.pieChartData.push(1);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.pieChartData.pop();
      this.pieChartLabels.pop();
    },1);
  }
```